# Register alternative tagprefix for standard controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to create a tag prefix for controls in System.Web assembly.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="SimpleCustomControl.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleCustomControl" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CC" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="System.Web" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <CC:TextBox runat="server"></CC:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But getting "Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter CC. Can not resolve symbol CC" error in VS. And no autocomplete is available after entering `<CC:`.

Is it possible to register such kind of tag prefix for standard controls?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a trailing space in `TagPrefix="CC "`?

Comment: No, it was a misprint